# Searchable Dictionary displaying Error on package name change

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Iam using [Searchabel Dictinary](https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/SearchableDictionary) code in my project to search a list of words stored in text file.

I've changed the searchable dictionary package name from "com.example.android.searchabledict" to "com.android.tspshikari".

This is the the provider in Manifest File:

```
<!-- Provides search suggestions for words and their definitions. -->
    <provider
        android:name=".DictionaryProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.searchabledict.DictionaryProvider" />
```

And the code in DictionaryProvider Class:

```
public static String AUTHORITY = "com.example.android.searchabledict.DictionaryProvider1";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/dictionary");

// MIME types used for searching words or looking up a single definition
public static final String WORDS_MIME_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE +
                                              "/vnd.example.android.searchabledict";
public static final String DEFINITION_MIME_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE +
                                                   "/vnd.example.android.searchabledict";
```

When iam building the code, the error iam getting is:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER]
```

When Iam changing the Provider Authority name, the error iam getting is:

```
Failed to find provider info for com.example.android.searchabledict.DictionaryProvider
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As searched from other pages, i found i had to uninstall the previous app. I was doing that but again on installing it was showing the same error.

After searching a lot on my mobile, i found that there is a option for *uninstall from all users* in the app section of storage in settings.

After doing that, my app installed!!